# What is the performance of log(n!) compared to n?

Tags: time-complexity

I was wondering if log(n!) is O(n), or if n is O(log(n!)). I have seen that log(n!) is O(n log(n)) but there is no information that I can find available to my particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) implies that `log(n!) = Θ(n log(n))`.  In particular, it is not true that `log(n!) = O(n)`, and it is true that `n = O(log(n!))`.

Comment: Why is it not true that `log(n!) = O(n)` ? Big O is all about upper bound. You can see my answer. Below a certain value of n, it is true.

Comment: @taurus05: Big O is a statement about the asymptotic growth of the function, not about its outputs for particular values of `n`.  In particular, `log(n!) = O(n)` does not just mean `log(n!) <= n`.  You may wish to study the definition further.

Comment: You're right sir. I understood it. Should I delete my answer? Or it might help? @NateEldredge

Comment: I think the graphs in your answer are indeed helpful, as they give some intuition for what is going on.  But I would suggest clarifying that they only suggest the correct answer and do not prove it.

Comment: Sir, it will be really helpful, if you could edit the answer, and remove unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Log(n!) grows much faster as compared to n.
You can see from the picture.
Example :
When n =50,
O(n) will be 50.
But, O(log(n!))  = 64.48.[image: Graph]

**Update** :

I tried plotting n and log(n!), on the same Graph.[image: Log(n!) vs n Graph]

```
log(n!) = O(n) for 0 < n < 25 
n = O(log(n!)) for n > 25
```

Comment: I am afraid this is based on an incorrect understanding of big O notation.  It is about the behavior of the function as n tends to infinity, and it does not make sense to qualify it with particular ranges of n.  The second graph strongly *suggests* that `n = O(log(n!))`, but it is not a proof since it does not rule out the possibility that the behavior could change for larger n.